# which mahanirvana tantra book is he following

Tags: mantras, tantra, shakti, shaktism

I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvF9x2xzdSI) of samarpananda, where he is explaining about the shakti mantra, I like how the book contains both the encripted slokas in sanskrit and the decrypted hidden meaning. The mahanirvana tantra by sir john woodroffe (auther allan) contains the direct mantras but it is exampt of the slokas and how to derive the mantras from it, as in this video. Can any one tell me which book he is following?